# What bug is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Saw this bug on a window in my house. Never saw a bug with antennae like this!

Edit: I live in NY, and saw this bug about 1 PM. Also, I found there were several more on other windows and I think I might have a problem!

[image: a bug with interesting antennae]

Comment: Please see here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info

Comment: I am not a good naturalist but I would say some kind of [Scarabaeidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarabaeidae)

Comment: Where is your location?

Comment: In case anyone finds it relevant: many of these bugs (10-20 it seems) were brought in from outside, nearby the house, with the firewood. Apparently these bugs are drawn to wood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure looks like a Deathwatch Beetle (*Ptilinus ruficornis*) with pectinate antenae.

[image]

Source: https://bugguide.net/node/view/59669

This [Encyclopedia of Life](http://eol.org/pages/1036286/overview) site also has some more information.

Comment: The antennae are also a sign of the animal's sex: both figures (Q & A) are males (the antennae of a female would be sawtoothed).